# In the real world, what happens if a transistor turning on causes it to turn off?

Tags: transistors

So say you have the following circuit:

[image]

I apologize if this circuit is super simple, but I have very little electronics knowledge. The program I'm using will be for building circuits out of transistors + wiring to learn the basics of logic gates and circuit design, it's not a full fledged simulator.

In the below diagram, the power source feeds into the base and the collector for transistor A. The base for transistor B is activated by the user. If powered on, and you power the base for Transistor B, that allows a connection between the power source and the ground which grounds out the circuit, which should close transistor A (power source no longer powers it's base) which means the circuit is no longer closed out.

In trying to determine what the behavior for this condition should be, I'd like to know what might happen in real life.

Comment: Turning on the bottom transistor will not deactivate the top one. Both are turned on and current flows through both of them. Since there are no resistors or any other current-limiting devices in sight, the transistors will possibly fry.

Comment: Are these NPN or PNP transistors?  Please draw arrows (pointing the right way) on the emitters, otherwise we can't say what will happen.  Also, label the components Q1, Q2, etc, for easy reference during discussion.

Comment: Also, you say "in the below diagram", but there is no diagram below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to show the below circuit and want to know what happens if the user raises the user control.

What happens will depend on which component gives up first.  The devices are each trying to maintain certain states, but they conflict, so they cannot all win.  In theory, we can write equations for each of them, but you asked real world, so I'll speak in generalities here.

1. The bottom transistor is trying to turn on hard.  About the best it can do due to the way a BJT works is to pull the collector to about 0.3 V of the emitter.  This is called saturation.
2. However, the top transistor wants to keep it's base to emitter to about 0.7 V.  This is very similar to how a diode operates.  As the base to emitter voltage is forced larger, the current will rise exponentially.
3. The voltage source for the power supply will attempt to maintain the voltage across it.  But in real life, power supplies have limited current capabilities.

In a real circuit, the exponentially rising current across the upper base to emitter will either pull the power supply down if it cannot handle the current or the heat generated across the transistors will destroy one of them.

2[image: schematic]

Answer (score 1):

The top transistor is diode connected, so it will act like a diode. When the bottom transistor turns on, you'll have a diode directly connected between power and ground: POOF! You let the magic smoke out because the diode will try and sink all of the current it can get from the power supply.

If the top transistor happens to be PNP (rather than NPN) it's not diode connected, but the source and base would be pinned to the same voltage so no current could ever flow regardless of what transistor B is doing.